# Dynamically assign to string key typescript error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having hard time with this typescript error in a redux reducer. I have created a simplified version as follows to replicate the issue.

```
export const CATEGORY_TYPES = ['cars', 'ships'] as const;
export type CategoryTypes = typeof CATEGORY_TYPES[number] 
export interface ObjectArray {
  externalId: string
}
export interface CarFilters {
  arrayType: string[];
  objectType: ObjectArray[];
}

export interface AppState {
  appliedFilters: {
    cars: CarFilters;
    ships: {
      [filter: string]: string[];
    };
  };
}

export interface AssignValue {
  category: CategoryTypes;
  key: string;
  value: string[] | ObjectArray[];
}

const initialState = {
  appliedFilters: {
    cars: {
      arrayType: [],
      objectType: [],
    },
    ships: {},
  },
} as AppState;

const assignValue = (params: AssignValue)=>{
  initialState.appliedFilters[params.category][params.key] = params.value;
}
```

I'm getting following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'CarFilters | { [filter: string]: string[]; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CarFilters | { [filter: string]: string[]; }'.
```

`AssignValue` is the replicated of code inside reducer ( redux-toolkit ). The problem seems to be the `[params.key]`. But both objects have string keys.

Typescript playground [sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIEEAqBRAcQHkAlATQH0cyAFPAZTgF44BtAcgQEMpV2AaOO1QALAJZg%20AXThdUiFOgDcAWABQoSLDgwAnmGBwMXGMADm0XTn3B5LPQYgAzI7kKlK1OvVbIArgC2AEbAUDLqmtDwYsimUE5cCIZEQQBWwAgwWFBQXLpwAN7qcHCgcchcADYAkgAmAFxw6FAxZuoAvhHgUXAxcQlJRjwAYmKVcfJFaiU8uVY2jc2trFKq03AQaRkw1gaNKemZ2XMra51qXVrRsaEDhlhgYPQwJoZTM4%20VYsC1o%20OhqEa7xKiB4gKGUD%20EzWIKa4kkQOKsLYTjGcUWMBayDMUgxWLMpyRJXaMLgJI66kuPT6t0S91QqDEZmQADUqn43kjuKYLFBdI1jDzLLtbKSANbAflNTGtUkAN3ZwDxyxkAB84Adtsc8oS1Od1Eg0NcxDAxFVnq9mIUkVxPt9fmiAYj1iVuLxncjZDk8iLGit%20ESQZtDjsFmwpAGXWTI7DRBJwQV2jHox1ZPIHk8XqY1gbFPA5IzmWzKhyrQAKMA8LgBcFYBlM1mKgCUTAAfMCYiazZULaYAHS2sBfH5QgGsSu5Gt97nmSxScdVqcS3QyFgT6uoPsKkvAM5AA)

What could be the problems here.

Updating with Suggestions from answer so following works perfectly.

```
export const CATEGORY_TYPES = ['cars', 'ships'] as const;
export type CategoryTypes = typeof CATEGORY_TYPES[number];

export interface ObjectArray {
  externalId: string
}
export interface CarFilters {
  arrayType: string[];
  objectType: ObjectArray[];
}
export interface ShipFilters {
  [filter: string]: string;
}

export interface AppState {
  appliedFilters: {
    cars: CarFilters;
    ships: ShipFilters;
  };
}

const initialState = {
  appliedFilters: {
    cars: {
      arrayType: [],
      objectType: [],
    },
    ships: {},
  },
} as AppState;

type AppStateFilters = AppState["appliedFilters"]

type PathValue<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends unknown ? T[K] : never

function assignValue<
  Category extends keyof AppStateFilters, 
  Key extends keyof PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category>
>(params: {
    category: Category,
    key: Key,
    value: PathValue<AppStateFilters[Category], Key>
}): void {
  initialState.appliedFilters[params.category][params.key] = params.value;
}
```

Then I tried to define the type of `assignValue` function as a separate type( Actually this is a simplified sample of a redux state update scenario, So I need to define passing parameter type separately for the action. ) and this time I want to update whole category ( cars or ships ) with respective value ( CarFilters or ShipFilters )

```
// It works type defined with the function
const updateCategoryFilterV1 = <
  Category extends keyof AppStateFilters, 
  Key extends PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category> = PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category>
>(params: {
  category: Category,
  value: Key
})=>{
  initialState.appliedFilters[params.category] = params.value;
}

// But when type is extracted, it does not.
type UpdateAppliedFilterType<Category extends keyof AppStateFilters = keyof AppStateFilters, 
  Filter extends PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category> = PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category>> = {
    category: Category,
    filter: Filter
  }

const updateCategoryFilterV2 = (params: UpdateAppliedFilterType) => {
  initialState.appliedFilters[params.category] = params.filter
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIEEAqBRAcQHkAlATQH0cyAFPAZTgF44BtAcgQEMpV2AaOO1QALAJZg%20AXThdUiFOgDcAKFCRYcGAE8wwOBi4xgAc2jacu4PJY69EAGYHchUpWp16rZAFcAtgBGwFAyauDQ8GLIxlAOXAj6RAEAVsAIMFhQUFzacADeKnBwoDHIXAA2AJIAJgBccOhQUSYqAL5hGpHRwXEJBjwAYmLlMfIFRTzZFlb1jc2sUqpFEClpMJZ69Ump6ZlTC6rtHRFwUTG9%20vTiYEMjwWOFbA7DMbMwTcgmUm8fJocqx00Zx68X0WDAYHoMCM%20nGsgh5TEwGqt1G9ThRW4vHqhigqPuSyKDWuqHqVwk%20N4hNa-xUSDQXTEMDEFShMPq4Mh0OMzHyjy4CKRKJe93Rj0xPFJfKJRMmOQ2wHqC344qJKx26xmbCkKplrV1RNEEileX1jzNNIBdjBELZxkpNjgnLtwFYACIBWBEciHW6pFarHAaEYRAA1Co%20YAAHhwxRAxmQ1Xk6rWggA0nGE0m4ABrYDaRxwWMsPMFpw4AB8vJwrDTMhKwET8h8yBzyAgAHdkHAAPxF2syerIYAAN2CAb0-TxIqgCt5wZgYYj0ed3OADsEbqxqDdFYnl2ulLnLAXS-Kkajq5hG7gbqNkl3APp6CnOMGM%20P0tkWXlWvdxnQP0DRTdIFSVPIGygMoqjqW8AEY3Vaf0jmfeByTAMlDw-QMWDhN0wB4Lg-AQ%20o3QAmA3TaAEHBbdIxBQWRUFQMQTGQcNz2jR5DGMMwoFyBsm1zfNCyve0Z1QQRHjTfNM0bbNS0LU92IvUT13EwRuNMcwqxLYSnCU5dL1tNcb003jtD3CsAAoCOyPwTVVbgePMN9nL4g0ilLeppO0Dy4BHZd6gMjijK5a9xNYMzzB1OAfL3VoAEp6hHCAxGqL8oiZFlyhdAA6T1vWFO5eFYWyiNQXKnK0vipFKwj7Ny0sZBYMqGoCjjaTkZjWOU4ArLyRAYXM%20pOElAQhO0Ea5WmPRxvayMlWEd5mnYGREpULqWLY5d%20sGtzJqEbdxq8oRpoVObArYAbIOgmoRrS9g4CQp6Eo2pitt63aquGw6xsEE72A7KAUBMHyLo4xauFWl6AU2nqdoG76XN%203hjvzEaQM1WbBHmxUrtkqCKjuoQHqetbXrh7aOK%20obkdG1H-vRoRMfOnHLo4KHydh974epxHab4kb7z4RmDuECA-GAKFfjBtmIbYdhofWynPv5-ahZJNGxdQCWpeWz5Zf89m4K5lWEb26rtc10WpvbRdgml5pDdxxalYpnmqcjGn1aEYWtbJbRAggcorOEQOAmDib2ASuWFoVt2AQAekTuAADlgA7BRqn0IJyk7JOU8qeAO2gHN5GtOBs%20eYd0o7JkRC0ER9Bo5A6JQOlFHgHwwGqGEor4ylQzg3koy4gX%20PjOT5AUpxVJvKSZIE7NgpU4zwuKiT%20n2nSgxDXrQpdUzx8smz6ociUff73zHhd2L8zaBKmArOFMuZVk13ywUfQi1qKqRmreS-1yrjWkyc4AACEfDFybt2CuYh5AlGyOkZEggmSVwgNYOAdtcoqArgAVR7jCTkhUjxWCjFfWSgkZ5OjXmJDevJqFz3UnAR4lJKHLz3oZJhG8NLH3nJwkK3DRi8O3jvDEFsfpXz8s8Yq9RKTmifJ3OA3de7GCvoPAATLyU%20dkpQENUcAYhQpSF6ASswKsL9kBZXfjCT%20XpjE-zPpVcezU4BAJkTENoQA)

Error

```
Type 'CarFilters | ShipFilters' is not assignable to type 'CarFilters & ShipFilters'.
  Type 'CarFilters' is not assignable to type 'CarFilters & ShipFilters'.
    Type 'CarFilters' is not assignable to type 'ShipFilters'.
      Index signature is missing in type 'CarFilters'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem seems to be the `[params.key]`. But both objects have string keys.

The definition of `AppState['ships']` says that ***any*** `string` can be used as a key.  That is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures).

On the other hand, the definition of `CarFilters` says that ***only two specific strings*** can be used as keys.  It does not have an index signature.

If `params.category` is `'cars'` then `params.key` must be `'arrayType' | 'objectType'`. Just `string` is not specific enough.

Likewise, `value: string[] | ObjectArray[];` is not specific enough because it doesn't ensure that you are assigning the correct value to the correct key.

The following examples match your `AssignValue` type, but do not assign a correct value to the correct path:

```
const bad1: AssignValue = {
    category: 'cars',
    key: 'objectType',
    value: ['a', 'b'] // assigns string[] where ObjectArray[] is expected
}

const bad2: AssignValue = {
    category: 'cars',
    key: 'someString', // unknown property key
    value: ['a', 'b']
}
```

---

I can improve your `AssignValue` type such that you can only pass in valid arguments.  `bad1` and `bad2` above are now errors.  I'm making use of mapped types, indexed access types, and union types.

```
type AssignCarFilter = {
    [K in keyof CarFilters]: {
        category: 'cars';
        key: K;
        value: CarFilters[K];
    }
}[keyof CarFilters];

type AssignShipsFilter = {
    category: 'ships';
    key: string;
    value: string[];
}

export type AssignValue = AssignCarFilter | AssignShipsFilter;
```

Unfortunately this does not make the error go away. TypeScript has a hard time understanding the relationship between the assigned key and the assigned value.

So for right now at least I'm `as any`-ing my way out of it and calling this an improvement.

```
const assignValue = (params: AssignValue) => {
  (initialState as any).appliedFilters[params.category][params.key] = params.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743223) your 'AssignValue' interface is overly vague. It is not suitable to represent the invariants about key-value correspondence you're trying to impose on your function.

But correctly typing your `assignValue` function is definitely possible with a bit of ceremony though. Using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```typescript
type AppStateFilters = AppState["appliedFilters"]

type PathValue<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends unknown ? T[K] : never

function assignValue<
  Category extends keyof AppStateFilters, 
  Key extends keyof PathValue<AppStateFilters, Category>
>(params: {
    category: Category,
    key: Key,
    value: PathValue<AppStateFilters[Category], Key>
}): void {
  initialState.appliedFilters[params.category][params.key] = params.value;
}
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOanMm)

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. I went though typescriptlang documentation as well and it makes lots of sense. BTW I tried extracting function parameter type out and define as a separate type and then I had problems. Question is updated with those changes. Appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/w8v3Pm . Wil this work for you? Unfortunately one cannot use fully saturated type containing unions to establish exact relations. The only way is to calculate types at call site. One way or another. Feel free to ask another question if you need thorough explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no my situation is somewhat different. I create a complete example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-toolkit-gqthp. Where I need to change is `UpdateAppliedFilterCategoryValueType` of filter/types to be a one type and get rid of anying in the reducer. Why it is like this is because of redux typescript project starting use redux toolkit so new redux slices can't use all benefits of toolkit.